# Table filter only for body rows

Tags: jquery

I need this filter to filter only `<tbody>` rows of my table and show only the `thead` rows as the result.

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $("#AR").find("tr").hide() ;
    var data = this.value.split(" ");

    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show() ;
    });
```

Update: need the filter to be case insensitive...Tried with this one but not working...Any help?

```
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function (a, i, m)
{
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
    .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for `tr` elements inside the `tbody` tag.

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $("#AR").find("tbody tr").hide() ;
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show() ;
    });
});
```

Comment: There should be a checkmark below this answer. Just click on it. This is to let people know this question has been answered